# How to get list of installed apps and their info (id,version,name) in iOS?

Tags: ios

I've been looking around to get list of installed apps and their current version and id with no luck, I've tried using ihasapp but it doesn't show all apps and their current version.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like it would be privileged information (security and privacy implications); where are you trying to retrieve it, and why?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the iHasApp Repository:

https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp

this uses public, documented api's and should be AppStore safe

Comment: I've already tried i has app, Please read my question again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Mac Program I-Explorer. It will give you access to all you apps. You can open their .plist files and read everything about them. You can get everything out of it. I-Explorer is free and available here:
http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/
Just use the free trial. It's going to work of ever! I hope it helped!
Julian!